# Producing an Error on input focus

Tags: jquery, focus, border

if you go on facebook when they focus on one of the register input fields an error appears, how would I go about doing this, I have had a go but it doesn't seem to work.

```
        _emptyCheck: function() {
        $('#login_form input').focus(function() {

            if (! $(this).val() ) {
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
            }

        });
    },
```

http://pixelhut.net/projects/tinyquest/_script/master.js I have called the function etc, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Have you tried this $('#login_form input').on('focus',function(){
if (! $(this).val() ) {
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
            }
});

Comment: @Rohit Arora no I haven't I'll try when I get home

Comment: Sure ,I would recommend using debugger inside your focus function and check whether it works while focusing or not . If it comes then do check what is the value of $(this) in console. Does it refers to the same textbox or not. First of all we need to check where the problem is ? then only we can resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code works. I just changed on thing (the event), because on facebook the error is triggered on focusout, not on focus (but you can do it on focus it also works)

```
$('#login_form input').focusout(function() {

    if (! $(this).val() ) {
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
    }

});
```

[See the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqMPB)

Comment: Cheers, it was a stupid mistake... forgot to add the id #login_form on the form, instead I added it onto the input, and yeah looking back focusout seems like a better idea.